# OpenMP reduction after parallel region declared outside function

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

Apologies if this has already been asked, I can't find an answer to my specific question easily.

I have code that I am parallelising. I want to declare a parallel region outside a function call, but inside the function I need to do some reduction operations.

The basic form of the code is:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for(j=0;j<time_limit;j++)
    {
        //do some parallel loops
        do_stuff(arg1, arg2)
    }
}
...
... 
void do_stuff(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    int sum=0;
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum) //the sum must be shared between all threads
    for(int i=0; i<arg1;i++)
    {
        sum += something;
    }
  }
```

When I try to compile, the reduction clause throws an error because the variable `sum` is private for each thread (obviously since it is declared inside the parallel region).

Is there a way to do this reduction (or something with the same end result) without having to declare the parallel region inside the function `do_stuff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the reduction in the function you can use static storage.  From 2.14.1.2 of the [OpenMP 4.0.0 specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf)

> Variables with static storage duration that are declared in called routines in the region are shared.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void do_stuff(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    static int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
    for(int i=0; i<arg1;i++) sum += arg2;
    printf("sum %d\n", sum);
}

int main(void) {
    const int time_limit = 10;
    int x[time_limit]; for(int i=0; i<time_limit; i++) x[i] = i;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        for(int j=0;j<time_limit;j++) do_stuff(10,x[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that the value of `sum` is not needed outside `do_stuff` since it is a local variable. What the OP needs is a broadcast-reduce mechanism (or whatever it's called) that is lacking from OpenMP. I would rather simply make `sum` static and keep it local so not to pollute the global namespace.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I did make it static but I gave it file scope rather than function scope. File scope is still better than global scope but I agree that function scope would  be better.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly does what I was after. Now to find the other problems in my code :/

Comment: Ok, a little more to this - I implemented this idea nicely, but I need to reset the equivalent of the `sum` counter each time the function is called. When I do that (in my code) via the equivalent of  `sum=0;` or `#pragma omp single {sum=0;}` my code takes about 7 times longer to run. Am I completely missing something, or should I just give up on this approach?

Comment: @Phill, 7 times longer seems rather ridiculous. Have you tried `sum` being global or file-scope instead of function scope?  Look at the editors to my answer. I originally used file-scope.  There are other things you could try. You could pass `sum` as a pointer. Then each thread would have it's own private pointer but which points to the same memory address. Then you could do a custom reduction using atomic or critical.  But really, I don't understand why it's seven times slower. Maybe you could show some more code.